# What do the different parts of "known_hosts" entries mean?

Tags: ssh, public-key, rsa

Below is an `known_hosts` entry. The part that starts with `ssh-rsa` and goes to the end is a public key. What are the other parts (the characters before `ssh-rsa`)?

> |1|KnbIIJIPrL/1p7ofUV74sK+j/Gc=|wrjOFnPgoF0afgH0PeRtRqSdgvc= ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `|1|` is the HASH_MAGIC, indicating that it is a hashed known_hosts entry.

The next two base-64 encoded fields (delimited by `|`) are the randomly-generated salt and the SHA-1 hash of the host.

If you are using an older version of OpenSSH, or if you have `HashKnownHosts No` set in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or ~/.ssh/config`, the entries are not hashed and look more like this:

```
remotehostname,192.168.1.100 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdn...etc...
```

Comment: This information about the HASH_MAGIC and salt and SHA-1 hash is not present in the Ubuntu manpage. Any source?

Comment: What is the salt used for? Is the hashing done for security reasons?

Comment: For some reason I could not get a matching hash of the host by `echo remotehostname | sha1sum | xxd -r -p | base64` in Linux.

Answer (score 9):

From the `sshd(8)` man page, **SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT** section:

> ```
>  Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers
>  (optional), hostnames, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are
>  separated by spaces.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  Alternately, hostnames may be stored in a hashed form which hides host
>  names and addresses should the file’s contents be disclosed.  Hashed
>  hostnames start with a ‘|’ character.  Only one hashed hostname may
>  appear on a single line and none of the above negation or wildcard opera-
>  tors may be applied.
> ```

Comment: I see "Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional),
     hostnames, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment.  The fields are separated
     by spaces."